Select the Name in the Data Validation list on a cell value then the same name run the sub macro
Excel VBA code is required to Select the Name in the Data Validation list on a cell value after the same name could be run in the sub macro.
E.g. Data Validation List assigned in "Sheet3" cell text value "B2". if I select the "AA" and then Call to "AA" Sub Marco run. I got error the code line "Application.Run Text".
The error I got:

Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined-error

Below Excel VBA code here: Excel version is 2013
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'Run Macro when Drop Down value selected
'VBA to run from Data Validation
'Auto Show Drop-Down List When Selecting the Cell
If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub

If Target.Address = Range("B2").Address Then
Application.EnableEvents = False

Dim Text As String
Text = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Range("B2").Value
Application.Run Text

'or

'If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then
'Call ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Range("B2").Value
'End If
End If

Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub


Public Sub AA()
MsgBox "AA Macro"
End Sub


Public Sub BB()
MsgBox "BB Macro"
End Sub


Public Sub CC()
MsgBox "CC Macro"
End Sub

Thanks for Advance
Sivapraakasam K

And what error do you get?

Procedures "AA", "BB", and "CC" should be in a standard module, not in the sheet module.

And what error do you get? –
Mr. Shrotter
Run-time error '1004':
Application-defined or object-defined-error

Mr. MGonet
I have tried the Procedures "AA", "BB", and "CC" should be in a standard module. but not working

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)     If Target.Address = "$B$2" Then Application.Run Target.Value End Sub

Error handling..... You set Application.DoEvents = False, but if your code errors out, there's nothing that sets it back to True.  Start by adding an On Error GoTo clause to handle when your code throws an error.  Then run a fix to reset the DoEvents.

Instead of using Application.Run, try using a Select statement on your text to call the functions.
